# Which Open Source Tool can I use to create a website tree diagram using Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, websites, diagram

Which Open Source Tool can I use to create a website tree diagram using Ubuntu ?

I was looking in Dia but it is not that simple.

Something like this would be good :

[image: Sitemap diagram]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org):

> Graph visualization is a way of representing structural information as
>   diagrams of abstract graphs and networks. It has important
>   applications in networking, bioinformatics,  software engineering,
>   database and web design, machine learning, and in visual interfaces
>   for other technical domains.

Perhaps with a little script to do the crawling first

Comment: It is what I did so far : https://bitbucket.org/natim/graphviz-sitemap/overview but it is not userfriendly and finally make too large graphs.

Comment: You should set `rank` or `subgraph`. Also I think it's better to separate all spaces in label names with newline `\n`. This may help you also: [dotguide.pdf](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation/dotguide.pdf)

Comment: Also if you are comfortable in Python there is [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/index.html) which I have not tried so far, but it's built on Matplotlib API AFAIK, so could be worth try